# How to update only one element of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am trying to update only one element of a programmatically created UITableViewCell without updating the entire table or the entire cell.

**Here is a part of my code:**

These is how I am adding UIImageView to the table:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
suggestedCellAvatarImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.bounds.size.width * 0.025, 100 * 0.25, 100 * 0.5, 100 * 0.5)];
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
                    suggestedCellAvatarImageView.tag = 400;
                    [cell.contentView addSubview:suggestedCellAvatarImageView];
```

And here is how I am trying to update the ImageView:

```
UITableViewCell * myCell = [suggestionsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[currentAvatarCellIndex intValue] inSection:0]];
                UIImageView * myLabel = [myCell viewWithTag: 400];
                [myLabel setImage:returnedAvatarTumbnail];
```

The problem is that I am trying to return a view Instead of UIImageView..

Any Idea on how I can return any type of UI element not just UIView?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageView * myLabel = [myCell viewWithTag: 400];
```

The compiler is unhappy because, as you say, `viewWithTag:` returns a UIView, not a UIImageView. You need to *cast*, to assure the compiler that this *will* be a UIImageView:

```
UIImageView * myLabel = (UIImageView*)[myCell viewWithTag: 400];
```

But beware - do not lie to the compiler, or you will crash when the app runs! Make darned sure that this view really *is* a UIImageView!

Comment: You need to stop and learn Objective-C if you're doing to use Objective-C. See my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch03.html#_typecasting_and_the_id_type And http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch05.html#_polymorphism